# GeoPandas: interpolate for time X in timeseries

Tags: python, interpolation, geopandas, pandas, time-series

I've got some position data as a dataframe per target. Dataframe for target A:

> `index   TimeOfFix   Lat Lon geometry
>   0   1478133083  -27.1124    34.3203 POINT(34.3203 -27.1124)
>   1   1478133085  -27.1124    34.3202 POINT(34.3202 -27.1124)
>   2   1478133094  -27.1124    34.3229 POINT(34.3229 -27.1124)
>   3   1478133610  -27.1124    34.3355 POINT(34.3355 -27.1124)
>   4   1478133611  -27.1124    34.3354 POINT(34.3354 -27.1124)
>   5   1478136813  -27.0822    34.3303 POINT(34.3303 -27.0822)`

How can I go about interpolating a position for each target for time X. I see that pandas has a resample method to fill in, or average, data to a uniform sampling time. I don't really care about uniformity, I just want a estimation of (lat,lon) at time X. Most of the targets move in straight lines so a linear interpolation would be fine.

The gaps in the data can be quite large, spatially, so getting the right projection becomes important.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Where is time X ?

Comment: Time X is any time not currently in the TimeOfFix (unix timestamps). It could be right at the end of the time series or somewhere in the middle.